# Winforms C# Outlook Style Calendar

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook, calendar

I have been tasked at re-creating an MS Access calendar in a winforms C# application.  What I had created for the users - they hate.  Basically I was doing a data-dump into a DataGridView where they could search by month, day or employee to get the Calendar events.

They have asked for a redesign to make this look like a Outlook Style Calendar front-end with a SQL server back-end design.  Let me say that there is zero budget for this project so purchasing components is not an option for us.

Has anyone had to create an Outlook style calendar that allows for multiple events on a given day, etc?  Do you have any examples of how to proceed?  Or any suggestions?

Comment: Pretty bizarre accounting.  They don't pay you a salary?  Use Outlook.

Comment: Yes, they pay me a salary. But this is a part of a larger project to rewrite an existing MS Access application.  The Calendar items need to be available in other areas of the new application that is why Outlook is not a workable solution.

Comment: what did you do in the end for this? did you manage to create someting or?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Codeproject has several WinForms calendars, e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/docview/WinFormsCalendarView.aspx