# Does Winforms have a DayCalendar control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to implement a day calendar in my code, are there any controls that can be sued for  (thinking of the monthly calendar here). Want I want to achieve is a look similar to outlook or gmail calendar. Is there any easy way to do this or do I have to do it manually?
Was thinking about using a sort of grid/cells combined with a month calendar. T.ex. you select a day and the added appointments get highlighted in the appropriate row that mathes the time for the event.

Would be nice with a control though...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Winforms C# Outlook Style Calendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851080/winforms-c-sharp-outlook-style-calendar)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only calendar control I know of is the MonthCalendar control. You'll have to create a custom control if you're looking at creating something that just displays the day. I would Google what you're looking for, chances are there are examples or already made user controls that you could use. You may want to search the Outlook Interop MSDN pages and see if there's anything in there - never know.

Comment: What about coding my own dayview by using datagrid?

Comment: That's totally up to you. I personally would not use a DG just because it's more for Excel type editing than display. You could make a number of setups do what you want.I personally would lean towards a ListView and maybe group by hour, or something like that. WPF would present you with some sexier options, I think. You can customize controls a lot more in that, but it's a lot different than winforms if you've never used it and the binding can be tricky at first.

Comment: Thank you Yatrix, I though I did mark some answers? I'll look over the answers again :) WPF is sexier, but our teacher wants us to go through hell before entering heaven haha :D

Comment: Do you by the way know how to custom edit rows by index? (datagridviw[1,1].value = "Hello" ... or something :P

Comment: You marked some answers with the up arrow, but the checkbox below answers is what denotes them as the correct answer. The up-arrow says you found them useful. So, your correct answer should get an up arrow and the check box.

Comment: If this question is answered, mark it as correct. You should ask separate (new) questions as a new question on the site, not in the comments. I don't personally care, but it's a protocol thing that some take seriously. =)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4368/discussion-between-yatrix-and-daniela)

Comment: Care to explain why I was down-voted, whoever did it? Is there a calendar control in .Net that will just display the day I'm not aware of? I'm fine being wrong, I just want to be proven so.