# How to launch Outlook calender and appointment

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook-2007

i have Windows Forms application with C# .net 3.5  vs2010. I want to use Outlook 2007 calender and appointment (Microsoft outlook 12.0 object library) to show appointments like Outlook for particular user from database.

While executing application it opens separate outlook calender and appointment window, but i want to open that window in my form. Please give me solution or if possible another way then also suggest it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Winforms C# Outlook Style Calendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851080/winforms-c-sharp-outlook-style-calendar)

Comment: I don't think that is possible - your only chance would be to recreate UI and use MAPI or Outlook Object library just as data provider - a task that will be quite complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any .Net controls for displaying the calendar appointments on the windows form. To get the required data you can automate Outlook without opening any Outlook windows, see [How to automate Outlook from another program](http://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/201096). Also you may find the [How to automate Outlook and Word by using Visual C# .NET to create a pre-populated e-mail message that can be edited](http://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/819398) and [C# app automates Outlook (CSAutomateOutlook)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomateOutlook-a3b7bdc9).

You can't embedd an Outlook window in your application, that is not supported.